# How do I capture React Router dynamic parameters in the parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to be able to store the child's `id` in the parent component. However, I'm not sure how to do so. I know that I can call `useParams()` in the child, and then pass the `id` back to the parent, but this seems like a roundabout way to accomplish this.

```
<Route path="/project/:id" element={<Child />}>
</Route>

const childId = ???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a state in a parent component, then send setState to the child and call setState in child component, after receiving id, using useParams();

Parent

```
const [id, setId] = useState('');
<Route path="/project/:id" element={<Child setId={setId} />}>
</Route>
```

Child

```
const {id} = useParams();
props.setId(id); // Or however you access props in your component
```

Comment: I was curious whether there was a different approach to this, but I assume this is the only way.